# Dynamic Datasets filters in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, django, chart.js

[The image shows the current output but no parameters for the user interaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFJFD.jpg)I have a chart.js line chart displaying data for a year. The data is coming from Django view (apiview). I want the user to be able to select a range eg. 1 week, 1 month and so forth.

So far I have the view as :

```js
class AcctReceivableData(APIView):
  def get(self, request, format = None):
    dt = [dates.dt for dates in FirstTest.objects.filter(variable = "Accounts receivable (days)", kpi_category = "Finance")] 
    value = [values.value for values in FirstTest.objects.filter(variable = "Accounts receivable (days)", kpi_category = "Finance")]
    data = {
  "labels": dt,
  "default": value,
}
return Response(data)
```

This is the html file:

```js
var endpoint = '/client/primarycare/acctreceivable/chart/data/'
var defaultData = []
var target = []
var labels = [];
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: endpoint,
    success: function(data){
     labels = data.labels
     defaultData = data.default
     target = data.target
     setChart()
     
    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
})
function setChart(){
 var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
 var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
     type: 'line',
     data: {
         labels: ["January", "February", "March","April","May","June","July", "August","September","October","November","December"],
         datasets: [{
             label: '# Actual',
             data: defaultData,
             backgroundColor: [
                 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
             ],
             borderColor: [
                 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
             ],
             borderWidth: 5,
             fill: true
         },
         {
             label: '# Target',
             data: target,
             backgroundColor: [
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
             ],
             borderColor: [
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
             ],
             borderWidth: 1,
             fill: true
         }]
     },
     options: {
         scales: {
             yAxes: [{
                 ticks: {
                     beginAtZero:true
                 },
                 gridLines: {
                     display:false
                 }
             }]
     ,
     xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            },
            gridLines: {
                display:false
            }
        }]
         },
         elements: {
                line: {
                        fill: false
                },
                
         
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Accounts Receivable by days'
              }
     
     }
 });
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am not sure on how to approach the scenario. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Are you against using other libraries or needing to keep this vanilla-ish?

Comment: I am open to using other libraries